# JSF 2.1 webapp fails to deploy

Tags: jsf-2

I have inherited a large JSF 1.2 webapp, and am migrating it to JSF 2.1 (under JBoss EAP 6.2) in order to take advantage of some newer features, most notably the "view" bean scope.  One of the recommended steps is to make sure my faces-config.xml is JSF 2.1 compliant, by adding the following:

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
```

This deploys fine until I add the last line (version = "2.1"), and then deployment fails miserably.  Can anyone provide me with guidance on how to remedy this?  The relevant log snippet (including stacktraces) is here:

```
09:14:25,785 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS014900: Content added at location C:\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\data\content\59\5c5c13259c8a46d31fe70fa87ad856a10801ed\content
09:14:30,504 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) JBAS018224: Unregister web context: /SWOMaintenance
09:14:30,508 INFO  [gov.inl.security.INLAbstractLoginModule] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) logout called for username=null
09:14:30,509 INFO  [gov.inl.swo.util.TimerStarter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) Cancelling SWOMaintenance timer
09:14:31,398 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SWOMaintenance.war (runtime-name: SWOMaintenance.war) in 882ms
09:14:31,398 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "SWOMaintenance.war" (runtime-name: "SWOMaintenance.war")
09:14:35,442 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016012: Deployment deployment "SWOMaintenance.war" contains CDI annotations but beans.xml was not found.
09:14:35,457 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) JBAS018210: Register web context: /SWOMaintenance
09:14:35,457 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) JBWEB001093: The listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener is already configured for this context, the duplicate definition has been ignored
09:14:35,473 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) JBWEB001093: The listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener is already configured for this context, the duplicate definition has been ignored
09:14:35,473 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.19-jbossorg-1 20131024-0833 for context '/SWOMaintenance'
09:14:36,284 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) Failed to define class org.ajax4jsf.tag.AjaxListenerHandler in Module "deployment.SWOMaintenance.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/ajax4jsf/tag/AjaxListenerHandler (Module "deployment.SWOMaintenance.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:273) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:311) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:420) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:371) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:314) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:263) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:363) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/TagHandler
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.TagHandler from [Module "deployment.SWOMaintenance.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 36 more

09:14:36,315 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) Critical error during deployment: : java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/ajax4jsf/tag/AjaxListenerHandler (Module "deployment.SWOMaintenance.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:273) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:311) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:420) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:371) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:314) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:263) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:363) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/TagHandler
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.TagHandler from [Module "deployment.SWOMaintenance.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 36 more

09:14:36,409 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SWOMaintenance]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/ajax4jsf/tag/AjaxListenerHandler (Module "deployment.SWOMaintenance.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:276) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/ajax4jsf/tag/AjaxListenerHandler (Module "deployment.SWOMaintenance.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:273) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:311) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:420) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:371) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:314) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:263) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:363) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/TagHandler
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.TagHandler from [Module "deployment.SWOMaintenance.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 36 more

09:14:36,534 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP container.

09:14:36,549 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./SWOMaintenance: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./SWOMaintenance: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93)
    ... 7 more

09:14:37,596 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SWOMaintenance.war (runtime-name: SWOMaintenance.war) in 809ms
09:14:37,596 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS014901: Content removed from location C:\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\data\content\59\5c5c13259c8a46d31fe70fa87ad856a10801ed\content
```

The list of files in WEB-INF/lib follows:

```
 ajax4jsf.jar
 axis.jar
 commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar
 commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
 commons-digester-1.7.jar
 commons-discovery-0.2.jar
 commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
 commons-io-1.4.jar
 commons-logging-1.1.jar
 DataLookupServiceWrapper.jar
 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
 domingo-1.5.1.jar
 FileUploader.jar
 httpclient-4.3.jar
 httpcore-4.3.jar
 httpmime-4.3.jar
 INLMailer.jar
 INLSecurity.jar
 inltag.jar
 INLUtil.jar
 iText-2.1.7.jar
 jasperreports-3.7.6.jar
 javaee-api-6.0.jar
 jaxen-1.1-beta-6.jar
 jsfCustomTag.jar
 KVSUtil.jar
 log4j-1.2.8.jar
 mail.jar
 oscache-2.2.jar
 poi-3.7-20101029.jar
 poi-scratchpad-3.7-20101029.jar
 SecurityRolesServiceWrapper.jar
 wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
 WSTools.jar
```

Comment: have you checked the jsf version installed in your JBoss EAP 6.2 app server?

Comment: It is using jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar and jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar.

Comment: Apparently the webapp itself is still providing JSF 1.2 JARs along in its `/WEB-INF/lib`. Is this true? As to pasting stack traces, just format it as code (select and then either press `Ctrl+K` key or `{}` button in editor)

Comment: Thanks for the Ctr+K shortcut.  I have now included the log snippet.  Hopefully that can be deciphered.  I also included the list of files in /WEB-INF/lib.  They are the JARs from the original JSF 1.2 webapp, with one exception:  I added javaee-api-6.0.jar so that I could compile.  As far as the other JARs go, I don't think any of them are JSF 1.2 implementations.

Comment: At least the Java EE JAR absolutely doesn't belong there. It's supposed to be already provided by the server itself. The Mail JAR is also suspicious, if this is JavaMail, then it's already provided by JBoss Server itself, so also get rid of it. Ajax4jsf is not JSF 2.x compatible (as basically said by the stack trace). Get rid of it and migrate `<a4j:support>` tags to `<f:ajax>` tags. The `jsfCustomTag.jar` perhaps contains JSF 1.x things which may need to be migrated too, depending on how it's developed.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, BalusC.  I have removed the Java EE JAR.  I have migrated all the <a4j:support> tags to <f:ajax> tags.  I have many other a4j tags, I assume those need to be migrated also, correct?

Comment: @BalusC  Thanks BalusC!  Removing those JARs and migrating the tags did the trick.